# How do I invert my join critera in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, criteria

I think this is a relatively basic operation in SQL, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

I have two tables, a source table I'm trying to SELECT my data from, and a reference table containing serial #'s and transaction #'s (the source table also has these columns, and more). I want to do two different SELECTs, one where the serial/trans number pair exist in the source table and one where the serial/trans number do not exist. (the combination of serial and trans number are the primary keys for both these tables)

Intially I'm doing this with a join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM source s
INNER JOIN reference r ON s.serial = r.serial AND s.trans = r.trans
```

I would think this should give me everything from the source table that has a serial/trans pair matching with one in the reference table. I'm not positive this is correct, but it is returning a reasonable number of results and I think it looks good.

When I go to do the opposite, get everything from source where the serial/trans pair do not match up with one in reference, I encounter a problem. I tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM source s
INNER JOIN reference r ON s.serial <> r.serial AND s.trans <> r.trans
```

When I run this the query goes on forever, it starts returning way more results than it should, more than are actually in the entire source table. It eventually ends with an OOM exception, I let it run for 20 min+. For some persepctive the source table I'm dealing with has about 13 million records, and reference table has about 105,000.

So how do I get the results I'm looking for? If it is not already clear, the number of results from the first query + results from second query should equal the total number of records in my source table.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you're just trying to find source rows that don't have anything in referece, use "where not exists (select 1 from reference r where s.serial = r.serial...)" instead of joining

Comment: The reason the 2nd query doesn't work as you wanted is this.  SQL will take a row in the first table, then evaluate each row in the joining table and show all of the lines that match the conditions, then repeat that process for the 2nd row in the first table and so on.  So you would probably end up just under 13 mill * 105K rows in the result set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need something like `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM source s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM reference r 
                  WHERE s.serial = r.serial AND s.trans = r.trans)
```

The above query will get everything from `source` where the `serial`/`trans` pair do not match up with one in `reference`.

As cited in comment from @Dan below `NOT EXISTS` generally has a performance advantage over `LEFT JOIN` in a situation like this (see [this](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) for example).

Comment: The LEFT JOIN solution by AXMIM would work, but the NOT EXISTS should perform better

Comment: @DanField Thanks! With that in mind would an EXISTS have better performance than the INNER JOIN in my original query as well?

Comment: You could double check this against the query plan (ctrl + L in SSMS), but I think they'd end up with the same execution plans.

Answer (score 4):

"LEFT JOIN" match records that match together, and return NULL for those that doesn't fit.

So, non-matching records all have NULL in column coming from reference table. This way, you can than add a where clause to return only records with null value in a non-nullable column of table "reference" (like the primarykey).

```
SELECT * FROM source s
LEFT JOIN reference r ON s.serial = r.serial AND s.trans = r.trans
WHERE R.serial IS NULL
```